# How to expand infinite sum expressions.

Tags: summation

I saw this in a paper (however, I cannot derive it):
We define the growth rate of consumption as $g_{C, s} \equiv \frac{C_s}{C_{s-1}}$ and use $C_t=\left(\prod_{s=1}^t g_{C, s}\right)C_0$ to rewrite lifetime utility, $\mathcal{V}_0=$ $\mathbb{E}_0 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \log \left(C_t\right)$, as
$$
\mathcal{V}_0=\frac{1}{1-\beta}\left[\log \left(C_0\right)+\mathbb{E}_0\left(\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \beta^t \log \left(g_{C, t}\right)\right)\right]
$$

My attempt:

$$
 \mathcal{V}_0= \mathbb{E}_0 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \log \left(C_t\right) =\mathbb{E}_0 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t \log \left( \left(\prod_{s=1}^t g_{C, s}\right) C_0 \right)
 $$
$$
 \mathcal{V}_0 = \mathbb{E}_0 \Big[
\frac{1}{1-\beta } \log C_0 +  \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t  \log \left(\prod_{s=1}^t g_{C, s}\right)
 \Big]
 $$
$$
 \mathcal{V}_0 = \mathbb{E}_0 \Big[
\frac{1}{1-\beta } \log C_0 +  \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t  \left(\sum_{s=1}^t \log g_{C, s}\right)
 \Big]
 $$
$$
 \mathcal{V}_0 = \Big[
\frac{1}{1-\beta } \log C_0 +   \mathbb{E}_0 \left( \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t  \Big(\sum_{s=1}^t \log g_{C, s}\Big) \right)
 \Big]
 $$

Why is $\mathbb{E}_0 \left( \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t  \Big(\sum_{s=1}^t \log g_{C, s}\Big) \right)= \frac{1}{1-\beta }  \mathbb{E}_0 \Big( \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \beta^t  \log g_{C, t} \Big)$?

Comment: It would be nice to know the paper you're referring to.

Comment: https://www.ecb.europa.eu/pub/pdf/scpwps/ecb.wp2635~a410b2944d.en.pdf    ...page 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

More generally,
$$
 \sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t  \Big(\sum_{s=1}^t \log g_{C, s}\Big)= \frac{1}{1-\beta }   \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \beta^t  \log g_{C, t} .
$$
Do it by interchange of the order of summation and summing a geometric series:
\begin{align}
\sum_{t=0}^{\infty} \beta^t  \Big(\sum_{s=1}^t \log g_{C, s}\Big)
&=\sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \beta^t  \Big(\sum_{s=1}^t \log g_{C, s}\Big)
\\&=\sum_{s=1}^\infty \Big(\sum_{t=s}^{\infty} \beta^t\log g_{C, s}\Big)
\\&=\sum_{s=1}^\infty \Big(\sum_{t=s}^{\infty} \beta^t\Big)\log g_{C, s}
\\&=\sum_{s=1}^\infty \Big(\frac{\beta^s}{1-\beta}\Big)\log g_{C, s}
\\&=\frac{1}{1-\beta }   \sum_{t=1}^{\infty} \beta^t  \log g_{C, t} 
\end{align}
Of course there are conditions that have to be checked to interchange the order of summation and to sum a geometric series.  For example, it works if:
$$
0 < \beta<1, \quad g_{C,s} \ge 1 .
$$